# Can't stop or restart Apache on Mac Os Mojave

Tags: macos, apache, macos-mojave

Since i updated to MacOs Mojave, i cannot stop or restart Apache anymore. When i run the command below :

```
sudo apachectl --stop
```

I always get an error like this :

```
httpd (pid 101) already running
```

To stop or restart Apache i actually need go to Activity Monitor and force close all 'httpd' processes. Sometimes it works but sometimes the only way is to restart my machine. This issue happened in Mojave, in previous versions i did not have this problem.

Any solution / hint ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `/usr/sbin/httpd stop`, or `/usr/sbin/httpd --stop`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Mojave, try:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

I get a pid error too with `--stop`.

Answer (score -1):

sudo apachectl stop

without the dashes worked for me on Mojave 10.14.6 in 2023

I got a similar PID error if using it with dashes,
so
sudo apachectl start
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl restart

worked fine.

Comment: The answer that J-M-D wrote half a decade and which the OP accepted already says that.

Comment: @schpengle please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). SO aims to be an high-quality Q&A site. Before answering, be sure to add original content